# iOS8 background fetch issue

Tags: ios8

I have used background fetch in pre ios8 without a problem. But in ios8 when i simulate background fetch on my phone i first get an error that i do not have permission to play sound therefore i do not get any local notifications. Then upon opening the app, the app crashes and i get this wierd error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'this request has been
>   neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it'

Comment: i have the same problem based on crash reports.In my case it was related with the apple watch extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is related to this
[iOS 8 NSInternalInconsistencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809191/ios-8-nsinternalinconsistencyexception)

Look for places where you call completion handlers you get from methods like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```