# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it

Tags: ios, background, ios8, ios8.1

I have reviewed the posts from others that seem to have a similar issue and they were not the same situation. None of the posted solutions were issues that I appear to have.

I am getting this exception in my Crashlytics log ever since iOS 8 was released. I have reviewed my background fetch handler and had other developers review it as a sanity check. It does not appear that I am calling the completionHandler more than one time per background fetch call.

As a precaution, I put in a boolean to keep the code from possibly being re-entrant and that did not seem to change anything - not that I thought it would.

I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to recreate this issue on my devices or in the simulator.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 NSInternalInconsistencyException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809191/ios-8-nsinternalinconsistencyexception)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error after calling the completion handler twice in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in the `UIApplication.shared.delegate` implementation.